# Declaring the type of 'this' in a typescript function?

Tags: typescript

I'm writing a [grunt task](http://gruntjs.com/api/inside-tasks) in TypeScript. I'm trying to translate something I already have in JavaScript.

So, when grunt runs a task, it runs a function. When it runs, grunt sets `this` to an object with useful properties, the same way that jQuery overloads `this` with the element you are working on. I could access useful properties like `this.files`;

```
grunt.registerMultiTask('clean', function() {
    this.files.forEach(function(f) { Delete(f); });
});
```

So, "delete all the files in `this.files`".

However, in TypeScript, I don't know if you can 'hint' to the compiler that `this` is a particular type, so I don't get intellisense. How do I tell TypeScript to consider `this` to be a different type?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

> How do I tell TypeScript to consider this to be a different type

You can do that by declaring a `this` parameter. For your use case I've added `this: {files:any[]}`:

```
grunt.registerMultiTask('clean', function(this: {files:any[]}) {
    this.files.forEach(function(f) { Delete(f); });
});
```

## More

- [Official docs on `this` parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#declaring-this-in-a-function)

Answer (score 158):

Now (from TS 2.0) you can specify function's `this` type by using [fake this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#specifying-the-type-of-this-for-functions) parameter (should be the first one):

```
grunt.registerMultiTask('clean', function(this: SomeType) {
    //...
});
```

> `this` parameters are fake parameters that come first in the parameter list of a function

More info [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#declaring-this-in-a-function)

Comment: [Here's the relevant documentation for the fake `this` parameter.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#this-parameters)

Comment: 'This' fake argument is a really hard thing to google for!

Comment: Seeing this (excuse the pun) and thinking its pure Voodoo =)

Answer (score 3):

While I found that is now possible with this:

```
class ClassyClass {
    prop = 'Juicy Strings'
}

function x( this: ClassyClass ) {
    console.log( this.prop )
}
```

I have come prefer an alternative that doesn't take up real estate in the arguments line

```
function x() {
    const that: ClassyClass = this

    console.log( that.prop )
}
```

Comment: Or you could use multi-line function parameters ;)

Comment: Using `that` feels most clean to me as well. TY @Jason.
Throwback. I recall back in the jQuery days doing a lot of `that = this;`

Comment: If you put it in the parameters doesn't that add typechecking when you call the function? So that would be the stricter solution?

Answer (score 0):

I have a bit of an answer. I can do this;

```
var self = <grunt.task.IMultiTask<string>>this;
self.files.forEach(function (f) {

});
```

which works OK. It's gonna have consequences, like not being able to write arrow functions...

Comment: You an still write arrow functions, since they will close over the `self` variable. `this` in the arrow functions will still be incorrectly typed, but at least you can save a few characters!