# Define type of the "this" variable

Tags: typescript, this

I am trying to use Monaco editor for editing the body of a function.

I managed provide the arguments and their types using global declarations, but I also would like to declare the type of the **`this`** context variable.

I could not find any samples or information online how this could be done.
Any idea?

Comment: Could you provide a code sample ? There are multiple ways of doing this, the simplest is just a `this` argument to a function: `function n(this:type, .. other params.. ) {}` but context would help

Comment: Thanks for coming back to me, I only try to expose the function body through monaco-editor
For example

`function(arg1:string){
//Only edit here
 console.log(this.value1)
//To here
}`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28920753/declaring-the-type-of-this-in-a-typescript-function/41358367#41358367

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Declaring the type of 'this' in a typescript function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28920753/declaring-the-type-of-this-in-a-typescript-function)

Comment: user1836822, would you like to see my answer and write me a feedback please. If you are satisfied with my answer, please mark it as accepted on the left side from my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using your example you should declare this variable first ... like

```
value1:string = "";

takeValue(arg1:string){

this.value1 = arg1; // here you add the value

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This feature is allready available in TS 2.0.

See official announcement from Microsoft:

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/6739

For example like follows:

```
class SomeType
{
    value1 = 'Some string'
}

function x(this:SomeType)
{
    console.log(this.value1)
    //your code...
}
```