# Define constructor function (prototype pattern) in TS? This has type any

Tags: typescript

I've stumbled over something seemingly simple that I don't know how to fix. I want to use a simple constructor function (not a class):

```
const Person = function() {
    this.name = 'John'
}
```

The TS compiler says:

> 'this' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type
> annotation.

But I'm not sure how I can set the type for `this` explicitly in this case?

Comment: You'd better use a class. As for specifying type of `this` in a function - https://stackoverflow.com/a/41358367/1113002

Comment: "(not a class)" But why?

Answer (score 2):

You can specify function's `this` type by using fake [`this` parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#this-parameters) as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41358367/1113002). But this is not enough as you also want this function to be newable. Type assertion can help here:

```
interface Person {
  name: string
}

interface PersonConstructor {
  new(): Person;
};

const Person = function(this: Person) {
    this.name = 'John'
} as any as PersonConstructor;

const p = new Person();
```

The above is allowed due to [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html), so `Person` is both type/shape and also value/constructor.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgArQM4HsTIN4BQyyIcAthAFzIZhSgDmBAvgQaJLIiulNiAGEctKAFcEYLFHxESEAO4AKAJTVe-ANwstBBMLBpMOZAF5kMUSAnBjisAAtgGNUZDKZxB04B0pCqeQAcgApLHsQQJZkOAxokABPaNj1HCEQEXFJKB09dIMABwCQBUM%20HBUNIA)