# How to declaring a function with properties in typescript react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webfonts

```
@Bind()
sdffsf() {
 this.sdffsf.fff = 'sdfsd';
}
```

like this, typescript always reminds me fff didn't exist
wanna know how to declare the interface of this method

Comment: Just walk yourself through the documentation https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/intro.html

Comment: this doc told me how to declare a function with properties in typescript not in typescript react.

Comment: It works the same, at least for the question you asked.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Declaring the type of 'this' in a typescript function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28920753/declaring-the-type-of-this-in-a-typescript-function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I learned something new here.

I found this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/28920916/13257176:

they also linked to TS this doc: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#declaring-this-in-a-function

```
sdffsf(this: {sdffsf:{fff:string}}) {
   this.sdffsf.fff = 'sdfsd';
}
```

I did not test this, you might have to make this a function or class method. Ie:

```
function sdffsf(this: {sdffsf:{fff:string}}) {
   this.sdffsf.fff = 'sdfsd';
}
```

or

```
class x {
  sdffsf(this: {sdffsf:{fff:string}}) {
    this.sdffsf.fff = 'sdfsd';
  }
}
```

Comment: really appreciate it, bro