# Add type hint for function to limit this in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, class, jsdoc

```js
let f = function () {
    this.aa += 1;
}

class A {
    constructor(f) {
        this.aa = 1;
        f.call(this);
        console.log(this.aa);
    }
}
new A(f)
```

how could I write a type definition for f? I want to make f only have `this.aa`.

Since there is `this`, so I guess using a class for f is more convenient. Maybe extends a base class? But how to write it?

---

f is defined by the user, so f can't be A's method.

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28920916/5289334) answer. [Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYlC8UAUwAWBLAzgLigbygENDcA7AVwFsAjCAJygF8BKBAPigDcB7dAEwDcAKCEAbCMCgAzXHERTypAMbB03UslZ4hUXVDRYAdMSgBqRAEZhjEUtGFMmKAEF8OvcTJVadYXqhK6pjAdOQq3HRIMrBa7v66BpjGhAhQVnHxUoZKhKKiKBiYzH7xuoGkmNzihqLcAOYFRsTFGTY2pBAA7i5RzEA)